# Reverse the elements in an array and push the reversed elements onto a stack using a single for loop

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, stack

I've been working on an algorithm that reverses the order of an array using a single for loop and then pushes each element of the reversed array onto the stack. I've been having a hard time getting this to work properly, but I may be interpreting the instructions incorrectly. The instructions are as follows:

> Describe in pseudocode an efficient algorithm for reversing the order of the numbers in A using a single for-loop that indexes through the cells of A, to insert each element into a stack, and then another for-loop that removes the elements from the stack and puts them back into A in reverse order.

I can easily reverse the order of the array, but my stack does not fill before the for loop terminates. My code:

```
public static void reverseAndPush(int[] a, int start, int end)
{

    for (int i = 0; i < end; i++)
    {
        int temp = a[start];
        a[start] = a[end];
        //only elements 5 and 4 get pushed to the stack
        stack.push(a[start]);
        a[end] = temp;
        start++;
        end--;
    }
}
```

If I remove the stack portion, the array is reversed successfully. What changes would need to be made to make this code run successfully? I think it has something to do with my execution statement `i < end` but nothing I've tried works correctly (lots of index out of bound exceptions). The instructions say to do in pseudocode, but I wanted to actually try and write the algorithm anyway just to play around with it.

### Edit

For the second for loop, I had thought of doing something like this:

```
for n to 1 do
     stack.pop()
```

But this is assuming that I must push all the elements into the stack using the first for loop. I could be mistaken.

Comment: Could it be that you've mixed two very different approaches, firstly, reversing by using an intermediate stack, and secondly,reversing in-place?

Comment: *and then another for-loop*

Comment: are you reversing the entire array or portions of it? why is there not another for loop when the question specifically states that a second for loop is used to place the numbers back into the array? It seems like the above code has elements from your question but it doesn't actually implement the algorithm described

Comment: If you are having trouble designing an algorithm, you'd want to break down your problem. That "and" in the method is a big hint you should split it in two and attack one problem at a time. Test driven development can also be a big help. Give it a try.

Comment: I did not include the second for loop as that part isn't an issue and I did not want to take up extra space. It could be that I am confusing the instructions, but I thought I interpreted them correctly. This is why I wanted a second opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick here is to understand how stacks work, more specifically where items end up when you add/remove them from the stack. The stack data structure is a LIFO (last in, first out) data structure, therefore the last item you add is the first item you get when you call pop(). Here is a function to do what is being described by your question using the characteristics of a stack

```
public static int[] reverseArrayWithStack(int[] arrayToReverse)
{
    Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<>();

    for(int i = 0; i < arrayToReverse.length; i++)
        stack.push(arrayToReverse[i]);

    for(int j = 0; j < arrayToReverse.length; j++)
        arrayToReverse[j] = stack.pop();

    return arrayToReverse;
}
```

Example

given an array of arr = {1,2,3,4,5}

1st for-loop - stack = {1,2,3,4,5}, all values are pushed onto the stack

2nd for-loop - start with index 0 again because when we pop from stack we will get back 5 therefore arr[0] = stack.pop() = 5, arr[1] = statck.pop() = 4, arr[2] = statck.pop() = 3 etc. This allows us to use the behavior of the stack's pop() method to place the items in reverse order starting at index 0.

Comment: thank you for giving your input, I very much appreciate it. So do you think I would use a total of 3 for loops? 1 to reverse the array, 1 to push to stack and 1 to pop back into the array? If this is the case I was definitely interpreting the problem wrong. Let me know what you think.EDIT: Nevermind, I see your point about LIFO. I think I understand now.

Comment: @FuegoJohnson i added some further explanation of how it works, hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

1. Loop the array from the end and push each element to the stack. This should have the first element in the array as first element. In the meantime you could use another array and populate it within the same loop, which would be in reverse order

2.In the second loop, pop elements from the stack and assign it to the array from the end. This way the array would be reversed.

public static void reverseAndPush(int[] a)
{

```
int sizeOfArray = a.length-1;
int[] tmp = new int[sizeOfArray];
for (int i = sizeOfArray; i <= 0; i--)
{
    tmp[i] = a[i];
    stack.push(a[i]);
}

for (int i = sizeOfArray; i <= 0; i--)
{
    a[i] = stack.pop();
}
```

}

Answer (score -1):

In Pseudocode:

```
FOR EACH INDEX I IN ARRAY A
    PUSH A[I]
NEXT

FOR EACH INDEX I IN ARRAY A
    POP A[I]
NEXT
```

Comment: Can somebody explain what's considered as a problem in my answer?